# Unable to edit datetimepicker material-ui in react js class component

Tags: reactjs, datetime, datepicker, material-ui, timepicker

i'm using a datetimepicker from material-ui/pickers in a class component (react-js). when opening the datetimepicker, and whenever i press anywhere (date, year, ...), the datetimepicker closes immediately.
here's a snippet of the code i'm using:

```
    import MomentUtils from '@date-io/moment';
    import { DateTimePicker, MuiPickersUtilsProvider } from '@material-ui/pickers';
    class ScheduleTest extends React.Component { 
          constructor(props) { 
              super(props);
              this.state = {
                   form:{
                    scheduleStartDate: new Date(),
                   }
             }
             this.handleStartDateChange = this.handleStartDateChange.bind(this);
          }
        handleStartDateChange(e) {
            const { form } = this.state;
            form.scheduleStartDate = e;
            this.setState({ form });
        }
     render(){
     const { form } = this.state;
        return(){
              <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUtils}>
                <ThemeProvider theme={defaultMaterialTheme}>
                  <DateTimePicker value={form.scheduleStartDate} format={moment(form.scheduleStartDate).format('DD-MM-YYYY')} onChange={this.handleStartDateChange} />
                </ThemeProvider>
              </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  }
  }
 }
```

Anyone knows what could be the issue?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong if you define your component name which is the same name with a component imported before. You should choose another name for your component. This is not right:

```
import { DateTimePicker, MuiPickersUtilsProvider } from '@material-ui/pickers';
class DateTimePicker extends React.Component {
```

Comment: i changed the name of the class and still doesn't work. the issue persists.

Comment: @HodaIbrahim I have checked your code, there is an additional wrong syntax. You should check again your code at ``return() {...}``` -> ```return{...}```. I've ran your code, I got 2 errors: ```TypeError: utils.getYearText is not a function``` and ```TypeError: utils.getDayText is not a function```, I think these 2 errors are caused by moment and materialui-pickers. I don't have more time to research. Anyway, in my project I use materialui-pickers with date-fns, it works fine, so you should try to use it. This is an example: https://material-ui-pickers.dev/getting-started/usage

Comment: @HodaIbrahim be noticed when you install material-ui/pickers with date-fns: https://material-ui-pickers.dev/getting-started/installation.
If my answer is helpful, please upvote and accept my answer. Thanks a lot.